# Xamarin.Forms iOS project builds but will not archive due to warnings

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have the iOS version of a Xamarin.Forms project that builds perfectly fine on iPhoneSimulator, but when I try to archive the project, it builds, but then fails to archive and gives me a red error message (and echoes it at the top of the screen) that corresponds to a warning in my project. I've never had this happen before, also I just upgraded to the latest versions of Visual Studio, XCode, Xamarin.Forms, NuGets ... is there a setting somewhere that I am missing that allows the archive to ignore warnings?

My iOS project options screen has "Treat Warnings as Errors" unchecked. Do I really have to alleviate every warning to archive for a test build?

Comment: What is the warning/error?  Have you tried just fixing it?

Comment: When you create an archive it actually doesn't archive for the simulator it archives for the device, try building on the device and see if it shows errors

Comment: @Jason it shows whatever the current first warning is, and yes, I fix one and then the next one pops up.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @G.hakim! After trying building directly to a device, it showed me that it wasn't code signing properly. After investigating, something had changed, either from the Mojave update or XCode update or on developer.apple.com, and I had to create a new signing certificate and provisioning profile and link it to my project. Now both the build to the device and the archive work!

So strange that the archive process was showing me the warning messages in the top status bar and in RED in the build output. Anyway, I hope this helps somebody else track down a confusing problem.